# Nothing could be less like

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of "nothing could be less like ..." structure? Sometimes I see it with a "than", and other times without "than".

Say this example -

> Nothing could be less like A

If we go by the literal meaning, it means to me that everything is similar to A. Am I right?

> Nothing could be less like A than B

Here also it means that everything is similar to A, instead of B

Am I right on the assumption? If not please tell me the meaning and explain how it comes, because if literal meaning is accepted, the meaning I suggested above is going to be true. Or is this construction an idiom?

Comment: So it's an idiom, and it doesn't follow the literal meaning, right?

Comment: No, the idiom is precise. It does not mean that everything else is similar to A, it means that everything else is either **more** similar to A than B is or **equally** similar to A as B is. Nothing is **less** similar.

Comment: @StoneyB I always have problems understanding such sort of constructions. I mean this explanation is clear, but if I get anything like such difficult construction I find it difficult to understand. How will I learn them? Any suggestion? And after that how will I come up with my own difficult construction like this. Any suggestion will be helpful. Please. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @StoneyB From other forum I got this - **Parrots and penguins are both birds, but nothing could be less like a parrot than a penguin. While parrots have colorful feathers and fly gracefully from tree to tree, penguins are black and white, and waddle awkwardly on land, and are graceful only in the water.** What does this line mean here? **..but nothing could be less like a parrot than a penguin.**

Comment: It is exaggerated, of course, but consider: 3 points of similarity to parrots are named: color, grace, and flight. A flamingo is colorful and graceful, and flies: 3 points, so it is very like a parrot. A magpie is graceful and flies, but is black and white: with 2 points, it is less like a parrot than a flamingo [is like a parrot]. A penguin has 0 points of similarity, so it is less like a parrot than either a flamingo or a magpie [is like a parrot]. And no bird can have fewer than 0 points of similarity, so **no bird could be less like a parrot than a penguin** [is like a parrot].

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that all the things in this world are only these letters: `A, B, C, ..., Z`. Suppose that we want to write them as a list, sorted by likeness: the one that is more resembling to A will be placed closer to A.

How could we write our list? (Given that "Nothing could be less like A than B.")

Here is one way we can write it:

> **A** C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z ........... **B**

<sup>I put extra spaces to make sure that B is really unlike A.</sup>

The list makes it clear that nothing (else in the list) is less like A than B. (Otherwise, it would be placed after B.) In other words, **B is the one that is the most different from A**.

So, I think, yes, you can understand it literally.
And if B is not explicitly mentioned, it should be clear in the context what B is.

<sup>(PS. Admittedly, I couldn't understand the sentence at first, and I needed to analyzed it myself too. So, I think a little diagramming helps. ;-)</sup>

Comment: Hi...I have heard a lot about diagramming. Does it really help? Where from I can learn them?

Comment: Perhaps the diagramming you are thinking of is something different, which is called "[diagramming sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_diagram)", which some people wold find it useful. (You can find some useful links there.) My diagram (or the diagramming I mentioned) was just a quick sketch of how A and B would be arranged, which I used as an aid to understand the sentence. Nothing special. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance, the other object of comparison would be known outside this statement.

> Bob: Look at this brand new B, nothing like A.
>
> Kurt: Yeah, nothing could be less like A.

Alternatively:

> Bob: Look at this new B I got, I wonder how it's like A.
>
> Kurt: Nothing could be less like A then B.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, **less like** is usually used to emphasize the contrasts between two things or situations which are mentioned explicitly or can be got from the context.

> Parrots and penguins are both birds, but nothing could be **less
> like** a parrot than a penguin. While parrots have colorful feathers
> and fly gracefully from tree to tree, penguins are black and white,
> and waddle awkwardly on land, and are graceful only in the water.

> nothing could be **less like** a parrot than a penguin.

According to the context, this sentence above here is used to emphasize parrots and penguins have obvious differences. It doesn't mean penguins are the most unlike things from parrots. As it's unreasonable. Apparently I'm more different from parrots than penguins is, right?

> Nothing could be **less like** the universe as understood by twenty-first century physicists and cosmologists.
> In the Middle Ages the Universe was thought to consist of the Celestial Spheres revolving round the Earth.

*Didn't found the source, extracted as I assumed.*

Another example extracted from [WordReference Forum](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/nothing-could-be-less-like.2453572/). You might get confused when only one thing/situation mentioned explicitly in the sentence, as the above example shows. You get a question like, **less like that than what**. I think in cases like this, you can find clues from the context. As I can see, again, here **less than** used to emphasize the universe understood by people live in twenty-first century are way different from the ones lived in the Middle Ages.

> She's only teasing me. Never have I felt **less like** joking around, but I have a role to play (Gray, 2016, p. 43).

This is a good example. If you don't interpret the context, you might feel difficult to get the point of the author. Here, the author wants to emphasize: now she doesn't want to joke than whenever she has felt, I assume.

Gray, C. (2016) *A Million Worlds with You*. 1th edn. New York: HarperCollins.